# Why Visual Studio settings are all serialized as String?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio express 2010 and I have a Windows Form app which uses Application Settings.

I've set few settings with Visual Studio IDE. I specified types like Integer or Boolean. The variables are typed well since I have option Strict On and I can bound typed variable with the matching setting.

My question is in the resulting AppName.exe.config : all settings in it are tagged as String. Why it's not serialized as the right type ?

The example below is an integer in my code :

```
<setting name="timeout_reviewed" serializeAs="String">
    <value>10000</value>
</setting>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, keep in mind that the settings file *is text based*, so: some kind of string conversion is not surprising. The most convenient way to store the integer value `10000` in text is the string `"10000"`.

But: [there are four options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229207(v=vs.110).aspx):

- `string`
- `xml`
- `binary`
- `custom`

Now; this data isn't xml, so we can ignore the `xml` option. And the `binary` and `custom` options **require lots of extra work from you**; so - `string` is the most pragmatic and useful implementation that solves 98% of common usage while also being really easy to maintain via any text editor. For *exotic*  scenarios you can still do your own thing, but you need to work harder at it.

Comment: Thank you, very clear explanation. I was wondering because users will modify this configuration file and it could be a clue for them if it was the right type. I added a "How to modify" to my app to guide them. Couldn't get my hands on your link. Very useful.